# Nodejs executing microvm with Vagrant : terminal simulation

Tags: node.js, vagrant, virtual-machine

### Introduction

I am currently working on a Nodejs project to run a simulation of an Ubuntu terminal in a secure way.
To do this, I intend to use Vagrant in the NodeJs application to run a microVM and redirect outputs to the front page.

### Problem

I don't know if the utilization of Vagrant it's a good solution, and how to do this.

### Question

Do you have a solution for executing a microVM inside NodeJS application, and redirecting the outputs to a front web ?